# How can I recover my files from a broken partition with a negative amount of used space?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery, partition-recovery

Scenario: I was flashing an IMG file onto my SD card for my Raspberry Pi. Or so I thought - it turns out I foolishly selected the wrong device path (D: instead of F:) and flashed the IMG to my WD My Passport Ultra 1TB USB HDD. Did this several times, wondering why the Raspberry Pi wasn't booting with the SD card. Each time, I was writing to the external HDD.

The HDD contained a single NTFS partition called 'USBDRIVE' filling practically the whole capacity of the drive. It contained around 400 GB of data (if memory serves) and the rest was empty.

I soon realised and after panicking a little, I ran Minitool Partition Wizard's Partition Recovery Wizard. I did a Full Scan on the entire disk. The Wizard found many partitions (50+) including, of course, many from the IMG file that I flashed multiple times. It also found the NTFS partition I was looking for.

"Victory is mine!" I cackled as I restored the partition. This was not quite the case as Minitool Partition Wizard did restore the partition but not entirely correctly:

[image: Viewing the partition in Minitool]

As you can see, the partition does not fill the whole of the disk, has a **negative** amount of used space and an amount of unused space larger than the partition itself.

Clearly, things are rather broken. Furthermore, Windows Explorer cannot view the HDD and wants me to format it. Right-clicking on the partition in Minitool and clicking 'Explore' displays a single folder which seemingly loads indefinitely (I've given it 5 minutes):

[image: Attempting to explore the partition in Minitool]

Interestingly, Disk Management seems to think that the partition is healthy and formatted as RAW:

[image: Viewing the partition in Disk Management]

Here's some additional information from Minitool in case it helps.

Disk properties:

[image: Disk properties]

Partition properties:

[image: Partition properties 1]

[image: Partition properties 2]

My questions are:

- Is my data recoverable?
- If so, how do I recover it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Reformat & recover from your last backup would be the simplest strategy... otherwise the best you'll get is a 400GB 'hole' in whatever you want to recover, where the data was overwritten.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I don't have a backup - foolish, I know. I'll make backups in the future!

Comment: I had kind of guessed. Backups are those useless things that just waste an entire drive & an off-site annual subscription... until you need them :/

Comment: @Tetsujin So true... especially backing up a 1TB drive using a byte-to-byte copy

Comment: You overwrote data several times and you expect to restore your files?  I have bad news for you.  Your expecting something that likely won't happen.

Comment: @Ramhound he overwrote the same spot of data several times. What falls outside of that spot can be restored. Moreover, Linux images for the Raspberry Pi are rarely bigger than 4GB... all the rest was not overwritten. Except maybe something small due to the really bad attempt at recovering the partition with a tool that is not suited for the purpose.

Comment: Check out my answer on AU: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271 If it works for you I might consider writing a summary here.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thanks very much, I'll give this a go. The Raspberry Pi image was indeed small - not much over 1GB.

Comment: How did it end?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Sorry, I haven't done this yet! I will do at some point.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Tried quite a few different utilities (including testdisk) Didn't try RecuperaBit specifically - I decided it was easier to reformat and move forwards after trying lots of different utilities. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Testdisk and RecuperaBit cannot be really compared. It's very probable that the former doesn't find anything while the latter would have recovered most of the stuff. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I know they are very different utilities. I gave things like chkdsk a go but when it came up with an ETA of 453 hours, I gave up on it. I'll backup in the future!

Comment: Just a note for future readers: never use `chkdsk` on a heavily damaged drive. It will worsen the situation.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Ahh! Didn't know that! Thanks for your help. I think the moral of the story is: BACKUP!